# Subscribes/Notifies in Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, sendmail, chef-recipe

I have recently started working on CHEF Recipes and was trying to learn about subscribes/notifies in CHEF

Scenario: Wrote a recipe to install sendmail package, have a local copy of sendmail.mc on CHEF that i am deploying on the Node[Client].

I read about notifies/subscribes and what i am trying to do is when there is a change in the sendmail.mc file at /etc/mail/sendmail.mc sendmail service should be cycled.

for which i am using subscribes .
But when i manually change the sendmail.mc on the client to trigger Chef to overwrite the file and wait for the service to be restarted for sendmail i see the below error

> - service[sendmail] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)

```html
package "sendmail"

service "sendmail" do
    action [:enable, :start] 
end 

cookbook_file '/etc/mail/sendmail.mc' do
    action [:create]
    source 'sendmail.mc'
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
end

service 'sendmail' do
    subscribes :restart, 'file[/etc/mail/sendmail.mc]', :immediately
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the duplicate **service** definition with the same name (*"sendmail"*) could be a reason. But also your subscribes targets the wrong resource **file** instead of **cookbook_file**!

Given that most users and public cookbooks use "*notifies*" instead of "*subscribes*", I would rewrite it to:

```
package 'sendmail'

cookbook_file '/etc/mail/sendmail.mc' do
  source 'sendmail.mc'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  action :create
  notifies :restart, 'service[sendmail]', :immediately # not sure about the *:immediately* here, usually at the end of converge is sufficient.
end

service 'sendmail' do
  action [:enable, :start]
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Roland.
Actually changing the file to cookbook_file resource worked for me.
And yes i will make a point about people using notifies mostly, thanks again!